# How to get next record inside the mysql result dataset?

Tags: php, mysql, dataset

Mysql gives us a dataset When we run a select query in mysql and we use while or for loop statement to get each record from this dataset. I want to know is there any function to get the next record inside this dataset when we get a record without reach the top of the loop?
something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

 $currentId = $row['id'];
 $nextId = mysql_fetch_next()['id'];
 ......

}
```

??

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Why not get the value in next loop>

Comment: because I want to set prev and next for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add another iteration that converts your resource into an array and also includes the next ID (assuming it's not necessarily the previous ID + 1, in which case this is all pointless):

```
$recordset = array(); $i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $recordset[$i] = $row;
    if ($i > 0) { $recordset[$i-1]['nextid'] = $row['id']; }
    $i++;
}
```

Then you can use $recordset for whatever purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM `table1` GROUP BY id");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $next = $row['MAX(id)'] + 1;
    }
}
```