# How to get the next highest record but not the highest record?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max, limit

This is what i have right now

What need to happen is that when the query run it should get a record where id will equal next id but if the record does not exist it should grab the next one but when i try and run the query below it runs and gets the last record which is the highest record

To make it clear:

Records in database:

- 1
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8
- 10

So if the query checks for a record 2 (which is not there) it should get the next highest which is 5 not 10 how would i do that?

```
        $query = "SELECT * FROM  images where images >= '$nextid'";
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));  
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

            $forwardid = $row['images_id'];
            $picname = $row['image_name'];

        }
```

Comment: it returns the highest because your select of >= 2 returns 5,6,7,8,9.  You then loop over all of them, setting $forwardid and $picname to each one in turn, and when your loop is done, you have the last two in your variables.  For how to change your query to get just one result, see the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  images where images >= '$nextid' ORDER BY 
images_id ASC     LIMIT 0 , 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM images 
WHERE images_id >= 2 
ORDER BY images_id 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another iteration that converts your resource into an array and also includes the next ID

```
$result = mysql_query(" your query ");                
$recordset = array(); $i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $recordset[$i] = $row;
    if ($i > 0) { $recordset[$i-1]['nextid'] = $row['id']; }
    $i++;
}
```

[Get the next record](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599708/2151290)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like following. i think it will help you.

```
select * from images where images_id=
(select Min(images_id) from images  where images_id>=2)
```

N.B: here 2 is your given 'images_id'

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
SELECT MAX(records) FROM images WHERE records < (SELECT MAX(records) FROM images)
```

take a look at this and run and let me know if you need something different.